# Invite Max No. of people such that everyone knows A people and doesn't know B people

Tags: java, algorithm, logic, max

I'm having trouble with an interview question/logic problem. Basically the problem is to figure out the **MAXIMUM** amount of people that can be invited to a party, when given an input with the following information:

**1)** There are a total of X people
**2)** There are a total of Y friendships between these people
**3)** Everyone at the party must know M people
**4)** Everyone at the party must NOT know N people
**5)** A list of the friendships between the people.

**Here's an example...**

**1)** 6 people in total
**2)** 9 friendships the 6 people
**3)** Everyone invited must know exactly 2 other people (be friends with them)
**4)** Everyone invited must NOT know exactly 1 other person (NOT be friends with them)

**5)** The friendships are as follows (where each person is given a unique identifier from 1 - N where N is the total amount of people, in this case 6):

**1 2**   *(means 1 and 2 know each other/are friends)*
**1 3**   *(means 1 and 3 know each other/are friends)*
**1 4**
**1 5

2 3

3 4

4 5

5 2

6 2**

With this input, the most people that may be invited is 4 (when you invite people 2, 3, 4 and 5). If someone could explain to me how to find the max in Java/algorithmically without a specific language, that'd be fantastic.

I apologize if this question is elsewhere, I'm not really too sure about what this type of problem/algorithm is called and I couldn't find it with the limited amount search terms I could think of.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Down-votes with no explanations are not helpful.  
They can also discourage new users asking and seeking help or advice.
I think that down voting question of new users should be avoided as much as possible. 
For those I recommend the opposite : explanation without down-voting.

Comment: To get help here I would suggest that you make an attempt to solve it, and add your code to the question, pointing to specific problems

Comment: Number known + number not known + self = 4.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve this sort of problem is with an exhaustive search of all combinations. In your case you're looking to test all combinations of people in the set of possible invitees. There is a fairly easy recursive algorithm to do this. I'll provide pseudocode to get you started on it:

```
findSolution(invitees, others)
    if conditions are met by invitees
        add invitees to set of solutions
    if there are others to test
        remove first item from others 
        findSolution(invitees, others)
        add first item to invitees
        findSolution(invitees, others)
        remove first item from invitees
```